# Как удалить элемент в линейном списке?

Tags: c++, list

Создал линейный список и заполнил числами от 0 до 10. Как удалить элемент списка, значение которого равно 5? Пожалуйста, подскажите

Вот мой код

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int n=0;
int i=0;
struct List{
    int id;
    List *Next;
};
List *sp = new List;

void fill_list(){
    List *tmp = new List;
    tmp = sp;
    while (i < 11){
        tmp->id = i;
        tmp->Next = new List;
        if (n==0)
            sp = tmp;
        if (tmp->Next!=NULL)
            tmp = tmp->Next;
        n++;
        i++;
    }
}

void show(){
    List *tmp = new List;
    tmp = sp;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout << tmp->id << " ";
        tmp = tmp->Next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void del(){
    List *tmp = new List;
    tmp = sp;
    int e = 5;
    int n0 = n;
    for (int i = 0; i<n0; i++){
        if (e == tmp -> Next -> id){

        }
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    fill_list();
    int l=0;
    while(1) {
        cout << "1 - вывод, 2 - удалить элемент, 3 - выход" << endl;
        cin >> l;
        if(l==1){
            show();
        }
        if(l==2){
            del();
        }
        if(l==3)
            return 0;
        }
}
```

fill_list - заполняет список;
show - выводит на экран;
del - должен удалить элемент

Answer (score 1):

Сначала правильно перетасовать ссылки (то, что указывало на удаляемый элемент, должно указывать на следующий за ним (тот, куда указывал удаляемый)), а потом просто вызвать `delete`.

Comment: Было бы неплохо ещё и сопроводить свои слова фрагментом кода. Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более подробные ответы.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct List
{
    int id;
    List *Next;
};

List *sp = NULL;

void fill_list()
{
    List *tmp, *last = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        tmp = new List;
        tmp->id = i;
        tmp->Next = NULL;
        if (sp == NULL)
            sp = tmp;
        else
            last->Next = tmp;
        last = tmp;
    }
}

void show()
{
    for (List *tmp = sp; tmp; tmp=tmp->Next)
        cout << tmp->id << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void del(int e)
{
    List *prev = NULL, *tmp;
    for (tmp = sp; tmp; prev=tmp,tmp=tmp->Next)
    {
        if (e == tmp->id)
        {
            if (tmp == sp)
                sp = tmp->Next; //при удалении первого элемента
            else
                prev->Next = tmp->Next; //при удалении элемента посередине
            prev = tmp->Next;
            delete tmp;
            tmp = prev;
            if (NULL == tmp)
                break; //при удалении последнего элемента
        }
    }
}

void delQueue(void)
{
    List *next, *tmp;
    for (tmp = sp; tmp; tmp = tmp->Next)
    {
        next = tmp->Next;
        delete tmp;
        tmp = next;
    }
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    fill_list();
    int l=0;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "1 - вывод, 2 - удалить элемент, 3 - выход" << endl;
        cin >> l;
        switch (l)
        {
            case 1:
                show();
                break;
            case 2:
                del(5);
                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    delQueue();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]